# how to concatenate a variable for a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript, datatables, concatenation

who can give me light on how to concatenate a variable for a hyperlink, I need to insert some '' in the variable but I do not achieve it, this is the complete variable:

```
        var newRow =
        "<tr>"
        +"<td style='padding:15px;'>"+data.TASK_ID+"</td>"
        +"<td style='padding:15px;'>"+data.DESCRIPTION_TASK+"</td>"
        +"<td style='padding:15px;'>"+startdateTimeUTCTask+"</td>"
        +"<td style='padding:15px;'>"+enddateTimeUTCTask+"</td>"
        +"<td style='padding:15px;'>"+data.ASSIGN_DEPT_TASK+"</td>"
        +"<td style='padding:15px;'>"+data.ASSIGNED_TO_TASK+"</td>"
        +"<td style='text-align:center; padding:15px; !important;'><a href='#' onclick='modalCi ("+data.TASK_ID+"); return false;'>"+data.COUNT_DISPLAY_NAME_CI+"</a></td>"
        +"<td style='padding:15px; color:"+ color_CURRENT_PHASE_TASK +";'>"+data.CURRENT_PHASE_TASK+"</td>"     
        +"</tr>";
        $(newRow).appendTo('#tablajson-'+ elemId +'');
```

I get this:

```
<a href="#" onclick="modalCi (T00591629); return false;">2</a>
```

But I need this (enclose between apostrophes):

```
<a href="#" onclick="modalCi ('T00591629'); return false;">2</a>
```

Comment: I get this:

<a href="#" onclick="modalCi (T00591629); return false;">2</a>

But I need this (enclose between apostrophes):


<a href="#" onclick="modalCi ('T00591629'); return false;">2</a>

Thank!!

Comment: Use `\"` or `\'` to encode them within the string

Comment: so escape the quotes or use string template literals

Comment: Excuse me, could you tell me how? I can't do it

Comment: This is why it's better to use single quotes in JavaScript. Outputting HTML gets complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in

```
+"<td style='text-align:center; padding:15px; !important;'><a href='#' onclick='modalCi ("+data.TASK_ID+"); return false;'>"+data.COUNT_DISPLAY_NAME_CI+"</a></td>"
```

In order to create the single quotes you need to add forward slash. Change this to

```
+"<td style='text-align:center; padding:15px; !important;'><a href='#' onclick='modalCi (\'"+data.TASK_ID+"\'); return false;'>"+data.COUNT_DISPLAY_NAME_CI+"</a></td>"
```

Comment: Not work!     <a href="#" onclick="modalCi (" t00592984');="" return="" false;'="">1</a>

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that the first double quote is closing the first single quote and likewise for the second set of quotes. Try wrapping it like this

```
<a href='#' onclick='modalCi (\"+data.TASK_ID+\"); return false;'>
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href='#' onclick="modalCi ('" + data.TASK_ID + "'); return false;">
```

The difference would be single quotes before and after the double quote

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code set:

```
let data = {
    TASK_ID : "T00591629",
    COUNT_DISPLAY_NAME_CI: 2
}

let link = "<a href='#' onclick=\"modalCi (\'"+data.TASK_ID+"\'); return false;\">"+data.COUNT_DISPLAY_NAME_CI+"</a>";

console.log(link);

// O/P => {/* <a href='#' onclick="modalCi ('T00591629'); return false;">2</a> */}
```